# Slow upload of image to server over mobile network in Android

Tags: android, http, networking, android-wifi

I try to upload an image to server over mobile network and the upload is really slow. If I change to WIFI it's better. Can you give me an advice how to fix this behaviour? I know that the cell network is bad but my image is not bigger than 90 kb.

I use httpurlconnection and MultipartEntity.

```
private synchronized final void createPart(String partName, String fileName, String imagePath, MultipartEntity entity) {
    WidthHeight sizes = ImageSizeConstants.getDefaultSize().getWidthHeight();
    Bitmap loaded = BitmapUtil.loadBitmapFromFile(imagePath, sizes.width, sizes.height);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loaded, sizes.width, sizes.height, true);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, bos);

    bitmap.recycle();
    bitmap = null;
    loaded.recycle();
    loaded = null;
    byte[] content = bos.toByteArray();
    ContentBody contentPart = new ByteArrayBody(content, Constants.IMAGE_JPEG_MIME_TYPE, fileName);
    entity.addPart(partName, contentPart);
}

protected int getConnectTimeout() {
    return 50000;
}

protected int getReadTimeout() {
    return 60000;
}

@Override
protected HttpURLConnection initConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    super.initConnection(connection);

    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(getConnectTimeout());
    connection.setReadTimeout(getReadTimeout());
    connection.setRequestProperty(CONNECTION_TYPE, CONNECTION_TYPE_CLOSE);

    return connection;
}

@Override
protected void setupConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, QueryBuilder builder, Integer httpStatusCode) throws IOException, BadResponseStatusCodeException {
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = builder.getEntity();
    addBuilderDataParams(builder, reqEntity);

    connection = initConnection(connection);

    connection.addRequestProperty(CONTENT_LENGTH, Long.toString(reqEntity.getContentLength()));
    connection.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(), reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    reqEntity.writeTo(connection.getOutputStream());
    os.close();
    connection.connect();

    httpStatusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    checkStatusCode(httpStatusCode);

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }

    rd.close();
    is.close();
    String responseStr = response.toString().replace(QUOT, QUOT_REPLACE_VALUE);
    initResponse(responseStr);
}
```

I've noticed that in H+ mode of cell network , sending takes 5 seconds which is really good for my app. Is there any way to optimize the size of the sended image ?

Thank you

Comment: Upload speeds aren't always the same as download speeds.  Have you tried a regular upload on a site (such as imgur.com, or do a speedtest) to see if it's faster there?  In other words - do you know for a fact that the problem is isolated to your code?  Also, how slow is slow?

Comment: It takes around 1 minute to upload the 80 kb image, my request is sended really fast but I spend an minute to wait the response from the server. Right now my ping is 751 ms, download : 0.03 mbps , upload : 0.04 mbps.

Comment: Over H+ mode of Cell network my speeds are 6.5 mbps download and 3.7 mbps upload.